# how do fetch the year wise data alone from timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to fetch the records based on year alone from table whose created_at column value is like Eg:'2020-03-10 16:47:32.226592'. I need to fetch the year-wise data from a table.

SQL column structure:

`created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Tried Query

`SELECT * FROM <table name> order by created_time ASC;`

Comment: `WHERE created_time >= '2020-03-10 16:47:32.226592`?

Comment: how do fetch the month wise data ? OR I am trying to fetch the records based on year alone ?

Comment: @James I wanted the year-wise data fetch query from created_time value.

Comment: @angular, the best way to understand what you want, is providing sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

for 2022

```
SELECT YEAR(current_timestamp);
```

prints 2022.

In where

```
WHERE created_time >= YEAR(current_timestamp)
```